# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header usando php

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou tentando fazer uma simples requisição via localhost a um server externo, porém, sem sucesso. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
$(function(){
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            crossDomain: true,
            url: 'http://meusiteaqui.com',
            success:function(e){
                //window.location=e;
                alert(e)
            }
        })

    });
```

Comment: Informe a mensagem de erro para facilitar a ajuda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque o `meusiteaqui.com` não está autorizando, há duas soluções:

**1. Autorize via Header:**

Você precisa adicionar isso:

```
<?
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

//...
?>
```

Na página em questão, para que permita a conexão de qualquer outro site, incluindo o `localhost`. Alguns navegadores podem continuar a impedir isso por motivos de segurança.

Também pode fazer isso no htaccess, **por exemplo**:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php|html|htm)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

**2. Utilize JSONP:**

Modifique o seu PHP para algo similar:

```
$seusDados = array('id' => 1);
// Exemplo

$seuJSON = json_encode($seusDados);

if(isset($_GET['jsonp'])){
  echo $_GET['jsonp'] . '(' . $seuJSON . ')';
}else{
  echo $seuJSON;
}
```

Pode utilizar algo similar à:

```
<script>

MinhaResposta(MeuJSONP){
   alert(MeuJSONP.id)
}

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://meusiteaqui.com?jsonp=MinhaResposta"></script>
```

Se quiser saber mais sobre JSONP [clique aqui](http://json-p.org/).

Comment: Está errado, o correto é liberar o endereço do site no CORS, pois com * você deixa que a api seja acessada por qualquer endereço, tirando totalmente a segurança dela.

Comment: @IvanFerrer, "via localhost a um server externo", o `localhost` poderia ter qualquer nome do domínio, *qualquer Host*. Óbvio que pode especificar o Host (e é realmente recomendado que especifique), mas neste caso o Host é indeterminado pelo OP. *Na resposta eu mencionei que "para que permita a conexão de qualquer outro site", então acho que está claro que isso vai permitir qualquer site se conectar, o que inclui o localhost.*

Answer (score -3):

Fazendo testes no localhost:8000, e usando Lumen do Laravel consegui liberar usando a dica desta postagem, colocando o código no construtor do controlador.

```
       /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 127.0.0.1");
        }
```